# overloading template variable specialization with SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-variables

The following code:

```
template<class S, class = void>
constexpr bool is_size = false;
template<class S>
constexpr bool is_size<S, std::void_t<decltype(S::cx, S::cy)>> = true;
template<class S>
constexpr bool is_size<S, std::void_t<decltype(S::width, S::height)>> = true;
```

gives

> `error : redefinition of 'is_size<S, std::void_t<decltype(S::width , S::height)>>'`.

Is it possible to implement the idea somehow or the only thing that can be done is comparing with all size types?

Comment: using `decltype(S::cx, S::cy, void())` instead of `std::void_t` please gcc/clang but not msvc [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3sfzYbWaG).

Comment: `struct` with `decltype` pleases all compilers [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d5jsqdYTY).

Comment: Not sure if you can do one template directly, but you can do two and combine them with `std::disjunction`

Comment: this might be clang bug [46791](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46791). Might want to report it to Microsoft, too (also the `void()` case).